# Derivative of gauge symmetry

Tags: gauge-theory, differentiation, gauge-invariance, yang-mills

This is a pretty straightforward question. Say we have a field $\phi$, and we apply the $SU(2)$ gauge symmetry: $\phi \Rightarrow e^{i\theta_a(x)T^a}\phi$ where the sum on $a$ runs from 1 to 3, where $T^a = \sigma^a/2$, $\sigma^a$ the Pauli matrices.

If I then apply the non-covariant derivative $\partial_{\mu}$:
$$\partial_\mu (e^{i\theta_a(x)T^a}\phi ) = e^{i\theta_a(x)T^a}\partial_\mu \phi+ \partial_\mu(e^{i\theta_a(x)T^a})\phi$$

**My question is** for the term $\partial_\mu(e^{i\theta_a(x)T^a})$. Do we have
$$\partial_\mu(e^{i\theta_a(x)T^a})= i\partial_\mu(\theta_a)T^ae^{i\theta_a(x)T^a} \mbox{ OR } e^{i\theta_a(x)T^a}i\partial_\mu(\theta_a)T^a~?$$

Indeed, I was used to do all these calculations for small parameters so this ambiguity was not present. However here, the two terms are not equal because of the non commutation of the pauli matrices, right?

So, which one is the right expression, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left[M, f(M) \right] \equiv0$ for any matrix $M$ and any function $f$ of this matrix. You have just a particular case, where $M=T^a \theta^a(x)$ and $f=\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} M}$. $\theta^a$'s are just numbers, not matrices, so one can freely commute them with matrices, which means that both expressions are correct.